# ELKI - Use List<String> of objects to populate the Database

Tags: cluster-analysis, elki

Sorry for the naive question, but I got stuck while following all the pieces of tutorials available.
So, is there a way to populate a Database db from a simple List rather than loading it reading a file?

Basically what I'm looking for is something similar to:

> List objects = ...
>
> Database db = ClassGenericsUtil.parameterizeOrAbort(ArrayDatabase.class, params, objects);
>
> db.initialize();

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the contents of your `String`s?
Same as understood by the ELKI parsers?

This will likely require some code modifications, because the parsers are designed around Javas `InputStream`. I don't suggest wrapping a `List<String>` into an `InputStream` although that would probably be the least-effort approach.

Why don't you try extending `AbstractDatabaseConnection` (or implementing `DatabaseConnection`)? The database connection format, `MultipleObjectsBundle` is not much more than `List<Object>` and relation metadata; fairly easy to construct.

Alternatively, you could use your own code to parse the `String`s into `double[]` and then use `ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection`; which will wrap the `double[]` as `DoubleVector` for you and construct the bundles.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice. Following it I extended the AbstractDatabase where I used ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection to initialize the dataset from a double[][] and everything worked fine.